# Laravel don't triger to ComposerServiceProvider Class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

The "view()->share(...)" I placed in the boot method of the ComposerServiceProvider file does not work. But when I put it in AppServiceProvider it works. I also added ComposerServiceProvider to "providers" section in app.php file.

The error:

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: test (View: /Users/devtools/Projects/sites/laravel/resources/views/components/backend/sidebar/menu-list.blade.php)
http://localhost/tr/admin/settings
```

What could be the problem? Thanks for help.

They are my codes:

```php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // ...

    public function boot()
    {
        // This code works when I put it in AppServiceProvider.php
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
            view()->share('test', 'deneme');
        });
    }
}
```

**config/app.php**:

```php
// ...
'providers' => [
  /*
   * Application Service Providers...
   */
   App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,
],
```

**routers/web.php**:

```php
Route::prefix(LaravelLocalization::setLocale() . "/admin")
    ->name('admin.')
    ->middleware(['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localize', 'auth', 'verified'])
    ->group(function ()
    {
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('backend.home');
        })->name('home');
    });
```

**composer.json**

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1|^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.29",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.4",
        "mcamara/laravel-localization": "^1.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "almasaeed2010/adminlte": "~3.0",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.3",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5.8|^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

**As you can see these are the file name and paths**

[image: As you can see these are the file name and paths]

### SOLUTION:

> The problem was that I deleted the "data" folder in
> "storage/framework/cache/". When I ran the "php artisan cache:clear"
> command, it gave an error. I added the folder and it's okay.

Comment: did you cache your configuration?  and for this you would use a view share not a composer

Comment: Hi @lagbox! Thank you very much for answer. But, the problem was that I deleted the "data" folder in "storage/framework/cache/". When I ran the "php artisan cache:clear" command, it gave an error. I added the folder and it's okay. Thank you. :)

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
    View::composer('*', function($view)
    {
        $view->share('test', 'deneme');
    });
```

and do not forget to add this too:

```
use View;
```

Comment: Hi @S.Kashizadeh, thank you for answer. But, it was not work. Actually the **ComposerServiceProvider::boot()** method doesn't work at all.

Comment: are you sure ComposerServiceProvider loaded in composer autoload??

Comment: also view()->share('test', 'deneme'); must be $view->share('test', 'deneme');

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by composer autoload?  How can I check this?

Comment: open terminal and run , composer dump-autoload to refresh autoloader. and then see what happen, also change that view() to $view.

Comment: Oh yes I did that. Still same.

Comment: In AppServiceProvider.php:
function boot() {
dd("test"); // it is works
} 
But, in ComposerServiceProvider.php:
function boot() {
dd("test"); // it is not works
}

Comment: look like to me your ComposerServiceProvider.php does not loaded at all. change namespace App\Providers; to namsdjfhbdskfjespace App\Providers; see any exception raises or not.

Comment: Yes, ComposerServiceProvider.php does not load at all. I don't understand the reason for this. Everything looks fine. I also ran the **composer dump-autoload -o** command. AppServiceProvider.php is running...

Comment: how did you build your ComposerServiceProvider.php?? try artisan, php artisan make:provider ComposerServiceProvider . load in app/config.php like App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class . and also do composer dump-autoload again

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. :( I deleted vendor directory and composer.lock file. And I tried again. But, it didn't work.

Comment: I also did not understand what happened :) I am going to add my composer.json content in here now.

Comment: look inside vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php and vendor/composer/autoload_static.php files for ComposerServiceProvider.php, if it is loaded it must be there too, if not you have problem with your composer and autoloading

Comment: Interesting, it is correctly present in both files.

Comment: it is not possible :) maybe you have capital character in name or ... .

Comment: Probably yes, but where in? :) Are blade files included in this?

Comment: i;m talking about ComposerServiceProvider.php file. no , this file never hit, so test variable never defined. it must be defined in providers , and inside composer , you said it is. after that you must serve your application . just it, if you die inside ComposerServiceProvider.php it dies, but you say it never loaded with php, so maybe file name it is not ComposerServiceProvider.php, it is ComposerServiceProviders.php or something else.

Comment: Hi @S.Kashizadeh! I am very grateful for your answers. 
The problem was that I deleted the "data" folder in "storage/framework/cache/". When I ran the "php artisan cache:clear" command, it gave an error. I added the folder and it's okay.